# Limit Google Cloud Platform instance bandwidth

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bandwidth

On Google Cloud Platform, is there a way to limit the bandwidth allowed for a specific instance? 
I mean specify a limit like 10TB of traffic monthly, or something like that.

Because from what I see there is no way to specify a limit like this.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Due I haven't found any ways to archive that, i have managed to create a budget limit on the project. In order to alert the administrative office if the customer is going to overtake his limit allowed.

Answer (score 0):

**There isn't any cap or limit of egress traffic for a VM's in GCP.**

As you've found out you can set budgeting alerts in your project.

To be more specific however you can [set alets for a certain product](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets#budget-scope) (refine the scopoe) such as Compute Engine or App Engine etc. Even more - you can set up alerts for a resources with a certain label. If you for example put different labels for a different VM's you can set billing alerts for those. It won't stop them from going over the limit but you will know precisely which VM is generating what cost and set alets with [different threshold](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets#budget-actions) levels (30,50,80%).

If you go with the labels then creating them (or adding to already existing resources) is easy - just have a look at the [documentation on how to manage GCP labels](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels).